# anomalous integer comparison result in c++

Tags: c++, compare

I am working on a project where the integer `selectedObjectIdx` is supposed to be -1 when no object is selected, and `scene.meshes` is a vector that contains all the objects.

This is the problematic part of the code, and the problem is described in more detail in the commented out code:

```cpp
struct Scene {
    // gets filled with meshes
    std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
}


// vector has 1 mesh
int selectedObjectIdx = scene.meshes.empty() ? -1 : 0;


// outputs the correct values
printf("\n index: %d \n mesh number: %d\n", selectedObjectIdx, scene.meshes.size());


// If I select the mesh, selectedObjectIdx == 0, which returns false.
// However, if I deselect the mesh, selectedObjectIdx == -1, which returns true

fputs(selectedObjectIdx >= scene.meshes.size() ? "true" : "false", stdout);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you compare a signed `-1` with an unsigned `0`, the -1 gets converted to *unsigned*, which makes it a very large number.

Comment: @Eljay Does that mean that the .size() value is always unsigned?

Comment: @hellwraiz The return type of `size()` is not `int`. It is `unsigned int`. It cannot represent a negative value, but can represent more positive values than `int`. You can't directly compare a `int` with and `unsigned int`. The `int` is automatically converted to `unsigned int` but converting `-1` to `unsigned int` is problematic because `unsigned int` can't represent a negative value. You end up with a huge `unsigned int` instead, which is likely much larger than the return value of `size()`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` (`std::allocator::size_type`, by default `std::size_t`) depending on CPU architecture and OS

Comment: looks like that has changed, now it is an unsigned type that can represent any non-negative values of of `vector::iterator::difference_type`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I meant to write "unsigned integer" and lost sight of the context.